# How do I append an Image in the DOM from a list using EncodedAbsUrl

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have 2 lists with 5 columns; one has Title, Question, Attorneys, ID, and attorneyPic. This last one is looking into an image list. I created a webpart for this so the the actual webpart looks like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    apiUrl = "/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl,attorneysPic/Title&$expand=attorneysPic/Id";
    topicsTitle = '';
    title = 'TITLE HERE';

</script>
```

The javascript code looks like this

```
var buildCards = function () {
                    if (filterTopic.length !== 0) {
                        for (i = 0; i < filterTopic.length; i++) {
                            var accID2 = accID.replace(/\s/g, '');
                            var faqItems = filterTopic[i]
                            var headerID = "heading" + faqItems.ID
                            var cardBodyID = "collapse" + faqItems.ID
                            var cardTitle = faqItems.Title
                            var cardBody = faqItems.Question
                            var attorneyPics = faqItems.attorneysPic.EncodedAbsUrl
                            console.log(attorneyPics)

                            var cardBuild = '<div class="card">' +
                                '<div class="card-header pb-1 pl-0" role="tab" id="' + headerID + '">' +
                                '<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#' + accID2 + '" href="#' + cardBodyID + '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="' + cardBodyID + '">' +
                                '<h5 class="mb-0 font-thin">' + cardTitle + '<span class="rotate"></span></h5>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<div id="' + cardBodyID + '" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="' + headerID + '" data-parent="#' + accID + '">' +
                                '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="'+attorneyPics+'" class="img-responsive"></div>' +
                                '<div class="col-md-9"><div class="card-body py-1 pl-0"><p>' + cardBody + '</p></div></div></div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                            $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
                        };
                    } else {
                        var cardBuild = '<h4>There are no results matching your search.</div>'
                        $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
                    }
```

What is happening is that the url given is the one from the actual list and not from the list items "https://browardauthor/Legal/Attorneys/Lists/attorneysBio/1_.000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `FileRef` property from your `attorneysPic` library, this is the server-relative url of the file in the document library, as opposed to the url of the list item.

Change your `apiUrl` to select the `FileRef`:

```
apiUrl = "/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items?$select=*,attorneysPic/Title,attorneysPic/FileRef&$expand=attorneysPic";
```

Then update your `var attorneyPics` declaration in your JavaScript to:

```
var attorneyPics = faqItems.attorneysPic.FileRef
```

EDIT:

Okay, this is a bit frustrating, but even though `FileRef` is a valid built-in field that you can successfully retrieve through REST when accessing a document library, and `$expand` on a Lookup column that points to a document library allows you to select *most* of the fields, it turns out that Lookup expansion does not support `FileRef` or any other of the related Url fields.  Which means for each item that is returned from your original result set, you will have to perform a separate api call for each image url you want to retrieve:

Initial API call:

```
/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items?$select=*,attorneysPic/Title,attorneysPic/ID&$expand=attorneysPic
```

Then You need to fetch the URL of the image from the library as follows (Using attortneysPic ID  you got from first REST call):

```
/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ImageLibraryName')/items(currentAttorneysPicId)?$select=FileRef
```

There are at least a couple of different ways to approach this.  The most straightforward approach, though would take the longest to initial render, would be to perform the secondary lookup for each item as you loop through your initial results, something like:

```
var buildCards = function () {
    if (filterTopic.length !== 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < filterTopic.length; i++) {
            var accID2 = accID.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var faqItems = filterTopic[i]
            var headerID = "heading" + faqItems.ID
            var cardBodyID = "collapse" + faqItems.ID
            var cardTitle = faqItems.Title
            var cardBody = faqItems.Question

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ImageLibraryName')/items(" + faqItems.attorneysPic.ID + ")?$select=FileRef",
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
                }
            }).then(function (pictureData) {
                var attorneyPics = pictureData.d.FileRef;

                console.log(attorneyPics)

                var cardBuild = '<div class="card">' +
                    '<div class="card-header pb-1 pl-0" role="tab" id="' + headerID + '">' +
                    '<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#' + accID2 + '" href="#' + cardBodyID + '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="' + cardBodyID + '">' +
                    '<h5 class="mb-0 font-thin">' + cardTitle + '<span class="rotate"></span></h5>' +
                    '</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="' + cardBodyID + '" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="' + headerID + '" data-parent="#' + accID + '">' +
                    '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="'+attorneyPics+'" class="img-responsive"></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-9"><div class="card-body py-1 pl-0"><p>' + cardBody + '</p></div></div></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
            });

        };
    } else {
        var cardBuild = '<h4>There are no results matching your search.</div>'
        $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
    }
};
```

However, you could improve the end-user experience by defining a single placeholder image that you initially render for each card, then have a separate function that executes after your cards are rendered to find and load the images.  So, first you would define something like:

```
var placeholderImageUrl = "/Legal/Attorneys/ImageLibraryName/YourPlaceholderImage.png";
function initiateAttorneyPicsLoad() {
    $('img[src$=placeholderImageUrl]').each(function() {
        var imgElement = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ImageLibraryName')/items(" + imgElement.attr("attorneysPicID") + ")?$select=FileRef",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json; odata=verbose"
            }
        }).then(function (pictureData) {
            imgElement.attr("src", pictureData.d.FileRef)
        });
    });
}
```

And with that implemented, you would update your `buildCards` JavasScript as follows:

```
var buildCards = function () {
    if (filterTopic.length !== 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < filterTopic.length; i++) {
            var accID2 = accID.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var faqItems = filterTopic[i]
            var headerID = "heading" + faqItems.ID
            var cardBodyID = "collapse" + faqItems.ID
            var cardTitle = faqItems.Title
            var cardBody = faqItems.Question

            var cardBuild = '<div class="card">' +
                '<div class="card-header pb-1 pl-0" role="tab" id="' + headerID + '">' +
                '<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#' + accID2 + '" href="#' + cardBodyID + '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="' + cardBodyID + '">' +
                '<h5 class="mb-0 font-thin">' + cardTitle + '<span class="rotate"></span></h5>' +
                '</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="' + cardBodyID + '" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="' + headerID + '" data-parent="#' + accID + '">' +
                '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="'+placeholderImageUrl+'" class="img-responsive"></div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-9"><div class="card-body py-1 pl-0"><p>' + cardBody + '</p></div></div></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
        }

        initiateAttorneyPicsLoad();
    } else {
        var cardBuild = '<h4>There are no results matching your search.</div>'
        $(".accordion").append(cardBuild);
    }
};
```

Comment: @William I replaced the apiURL and the var but I got this message
`https://browardauthor/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items$select=*,attorneysPic/Title,attorneysPic/FileRef&$expand=attorneysPic 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: oops look like we are missing the question mark after `/items`, I just updated my answer post, give this a try:  `https://browardauthor/Legal/Attorneys/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('attorneysBio')/items?$select=*,attorneysPic/Title,attorneysPic/FileRef&$expand=attorneysPic`

Comment: This is what I got
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @william I have a tried a couple of things but no results yet. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I have a tried a couple of things but no results yet. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: I did some testing on my end, and it turns out that even though you can get the `FileRef` when you query the image library item directly, the `FileRef` field is Not available through a Lookup `$expand`.  I updated my answer with two different approaches for working around the problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply will try it and let you know how it works.
Thanks